# Waiting for modal promise in Angular error interceptor

Tags: angularjs, promise, bootstrap-modal, angular-promise

I am using a promise to query a service from my web-app. If the token is invalid, I now want to ask the user for the credentials using a modal, query a new token from the backend, rerun the failed request and return into the success block of the promise of my initial request to continue as nothing happened.

So I setup an error interceptor to catch a 401, and open a modal asking for credentials. Then I use the existing AuthService to query a token and return $http(response.config) with the adjusted token.

Here is my initial request:

```
MyService.getData().then(
    function(result) {
        console.log("process data");
    }
    , function(response) {
        console.log("error occurred retrieving data");
    }
);
```

Here is my error interceptor, reacting on 401s:

```
Restangular.setErrorInterceptor(
        function(response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                console.log("interceptor catches");

                var modal = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: "frame/view/Relogin.html",
                    controller: "ReloginController",
                });

                console.log("opened modal");

                return modal.result.then(function(data) {
                    console.log("get new token");
                    return AuthService.authenticate(data[0], data[1]).then(
                        function (token) {
                            console.log("set new token");                                
                        },
                        function(){
                            console.log("failed getting new token");
                        })
                        .then(function() {
                            console.log("now rerun request");
                            return $http(response.config);
                        });
                });
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        });
```

What happens now, is that the interceptor catches the 401, and opens the modal. But instead of waiting for the user input now and querying the backend for a new token, the error block of the promise is now accessed.

So the console output is:

```
interceptor catches
opened modal
error occurred retrieving data

get new token
set new token
now rerun request
```

But I wanted it to be:

```
interceptor catches
opened modal
get new token
set new token
now rerun request
process data
```

I assume there is a mistake in using promises... Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I mixed up Restangular and Angular. Just following the example [here](http://thecodebarbarian.com/2015/01/24/angularjs-interceptors), I finally figured out the issue. Setting up the error interceptor in >Angular< looks like:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $injector) {
        return {
            responseError: function(response) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    console.log("interceptor catches");

                    var modal = $injector.get('$uibModal').open({
                        templateUrl: "frame/view/Relogin.html",
                        controller: "ReloginController",
                    });

                    return modal.result.then(function(data) {

                        return $injector.get('AuthService').authenticate(data[0], data[1]).then(
                            function (token) {
                                console.log("set new token");                                
                            },
                            function(){
                                console.log("failed getting new token");
                            })
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log("now rerun request");
                        return $injector.get('$http')(response.config);
                    });
            });
        }

        return $q.reject(response);
    });
```